# Is there a term that combines present will and future will?

Tags: terminology

So, when we say to a child not to touch hot object, even if their will is to touch it, we refer to future will: the child will be hurt by it and the result of that will be undesirable, which means that future will of the child will be *not to touch hot object*.

So, we take into account the future will when say someone not to do something sometimes. But is there any estabilished term denoting both present and future will?

I am asking that because I am wondering if the ethics/morals taking into the account both present and future will can be named "will consequentialism". Or another wording for will generalized to the whole time continuum could be named "sense" but I am unsure about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I tell a child that a hot object *is never to be touched*, this covers both present and future. It is not to be touched now and it is not to be touched in future.

One might also say, 'hot objects are not to be touched', and here too there is an equal inclusion of present and future.

So, I don't think there is 'a term' but there is certainly appropriate tensed language.

Comment: Yes, I meant that will usually stands for something that exists right now, while in reality people are taking consequences into account. That's the main reason why hard drugs are prohibited everywhere. So, now I am considering the term "will consequentialism" but not sure whether it is proper, since it takes both current and future will into account.

Comment: You might need to change the phrase : 'will consequentialism'. Why not - this is just a suggestion - 'consequentialsm' ? Consequentialism involves the future consequences of present actions. But you may be looking at something deeper - the consequences of what we currently will for the future state of the will. Is that your angle of interest ? I am only trying to help. So forgive me if I misunderstand you. Best : GT

Comment: I mean that moral is determined by future will as well. E.g. we try to prevent some actions of people directed towards themselves because they will regret it.